# How to rebuild a keras model from a saved keras config in a hkl or any?

Tags: python, arrays, keras, save, load

I have the following code that trains and saves a model into a hickle file (could be any kind of file too)

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import load_model

import hickle as hkl

import numpy as np

class Model:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.metrics = []
        self.model = self.__build_model()

    def __build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu', input_shape=(3,)))
        model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))
        model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    def train(self, epochs):
        self.model.fit(self.data[:, :-1], self.data[:,-1], epochs=epochs)
        return self

    def test(self, data):
        self.metrics = self.model.evaluate(data[:, :-1], data[:, -1])
        return self

    def predict(self, input):
        return self.model.predict(input)

    def save(self, path):
      data = {'metrics': self.metrics, 'k_model': self.model.get_config()}
      hkl.dump(data, path, mode='w')
      return self

    def load(self, path):
      data = hkl.load('model.hkl')
      self.metrics = data['metrics']
      self.model = Sequential.from_config(data['k_model'])
      return self

def train():
    train_data = np.random.rand(1000, 4)
    test_data = np.random.rand(100, 4)
    print("TRAINING, TESTING & SAVING..")
    model = Model(train_data)\
                .train(epochs=5)\
                .test(test_data)\
                .save('./model.hkl')
    print('metrics: ', model.metrics)
    conf = model.model.get_config()
    print("type: ", type(conf))
    print("length: ", len(conf))    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()

    print('USING SAVED MODEL..')
    model = Model()
    model.load('./model.hkl')
    print(model.metrics)
```

This prints the error

```
    TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not PyContainer
```

What is wrong? Is the error form keras or from hickle?

NB. Here i'm just saving the metrics, but it can include any other additional information

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I answered something similar on another question. This is how I always save keras model:

```
model.save('model.h5')
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
```

for loading saved model:

```
model = load_model('model_w1.h5')
```

print out the summary:

```
model.summary()
```

To train again, you can use `fit` directly after loading.
and if you want to use it in some application then first make it global(**no need to do reloading for every prediction**) load model and then its weights:

```
def load_model():

    global model

    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    model_json = json_file.read()
    model = model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights("model.h5")
    model._make_predict_function()
```